# Jquery css selected menu issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i have a jquery for changing a menu color when selected

```
.selected{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```js
$("#nav-container>li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected')
        .siblings()
        .removeClass('selected');
});
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<ul id="nav-container">
    <li id="welcome">
        <a href="/" >Welcome</a>
    </li>

    <li id="find">
        <a href="/find">Find</a>
    </li>

    <li id="talk">
        <a href="/talk">Talk</a>
    </li>

    <li id="events">
        <a href="/event">Events</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The color changes take place, but when the page is at new page or page reload to new page,
the color is no longer are selected. What have I not added yet? Am I missing anything here?

Comment: You need some method of storing the current selected item across page requests. You can do this by cookies, or even a hidden field in the page which you can read the value of.

Comment: In other words, what you are missing is the basic understanding of the page life cycle.

Comment: do this selection in server side

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't know which one you selected after a page reload, you'll have to set the `selected` class via a server-side code (php) or on page load check which page you are on in jQuery and set the `selected` class on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the effect of an addClass only take effect on the Current Document. You may work with SessionID and PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(function(){
    var $ul = $("#nav-container");
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var $a = $('a[href="'+path+'"]', $ul);
    if ( $a && $a.length ) {
        var $li = $a.parent();
        $li.addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

and remove the click function that you have.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour. The Javascript context is specific to a page. If you reload the page, even if some of the HTML markup is the same, its Javascript-set attributes will be reset.

You can achieve persistent element highlighting using cookies or server-side code (sessions).

You can set a cookie [like this](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/), if you use the [jquery-cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) :

```
 $("#nav-container>li").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected')
        .siblings()
        .removeClass('selected');
        $.cookie("selected", $(this).attr('id'), { path: '/' })
 });

 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#" + $.cookie("selected")).addClass('selected')
 });
```

Note: didn't test this code, but it should work. Of course, the user needs to have cookies enabled to use this.